# Refresh list view in activity 2 when going through acitivity 1

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

In my application there are two activities, and in the second activity there is listview. List view is getting populated using the custom cursor adapter.

My requirement is when I go to the 2nd activity from activity 1 then I want the list view in second activity to get populated.

What I have tried:

1. Created object to second activity and tried but not worked also discovered that it is wrong to create object to activity class as activity class is internally considered as thread. So this way I couldn't proceed.
2. Call the list view from constructor of the second activity but when I passed the parameters as constructor and context. I am getting exception

Note: I am unable to provide the logcat here.

Below is the code.

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.testdb;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Database d=new Database(this);

final Button A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

A.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                intent i=new intent(v.this,abc.class)
        startactivity(i);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Second activity:

```
public class abc extends Activity{

    
    String getentry;
    private int storeID=0;
    DatabaseObject d;
    StockTable st;
    private String getstocks;
    public Cursor a1;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stockmanager);
        d=new DatabaseObject(getApplicationContext());
        st=new StockTable(getApplicationContext());
    final Button AddStock=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         final EditText entry=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final Button BroDetail=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final ListView popstocks=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        AddStock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                getentry=entry.getText().toString();
                //st.insert(getentry);
                System.out.println(getentry);
                //d.db.rawQuery(st.select(), null);
                d.d.db.insert(st.tablename, null,st.insert(getentry));
                //populatelist populatestocks=new populatelist();

                getstocks="Select " + st.column1 + " as _ID, " + st.column2 + " From "+ st.tablename;
                 System.out.println(getstocks);
                a1=d.d.db.rawQuery(getstocks, null);
                if(a1.moveToNext()){

                    System.out.println(a1.getCount());  
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("can't open database");
                }

                poplist populatestocks=new poplist(getApplicationContext(),a1) ;
                popstocks.setAdapter(populatestocks);

            }
        });
                }


    public class poplist extends CursorAdapter{

        public poplist(Context context, Cursor c) {
            super(context, c);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        //StockTable st1=new StockTable(getApplicationContext());
        //Database d1=new Database(getApplicationContext());


        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final CheckBox cb=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            final Button view1=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1); 

            if(c.moveToFirst()){

                //cb.setText(a1.getString(a1.getColumnIndex(st1.column2)));
                    //do{
                        //cb.setText(a1.getString(a1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(st.column2)));
                cb.setText(c.getString(1));
                //  }while (a1.moveToNext());

                }

        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stocklist, parent, false);
                    bindView(v, context, c);
                   return v;
//          return null;
        }


    }

    public void Declerations(){


    }


}
```

How can I refresh the list view in second activity when I am getting directed from activity one using intent?

Comment: startactivity(i); change this.Are you want to element show in list after adding in database? If yes, then try youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Actually my list view is in activty 2 can I use this in activity 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use Intent extras?
Like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, abc.class);
i.putExtra("loadData", true);
i.putExtra("data", listData);
//add any data you need
...
startActivity(i);
```

and then in activity `abc` check if there is passed data in `onCreate` or `onResume`

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
if(data != null) {
    //get the data
    boolean loadData = data.getBoolean("loadData");
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:**
You need to populate your list in `onCreate` of the second activity.
It is also useful to save/restore your data with `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` in case that screen orientation changes.
Check this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Boban but I want to populate the list view in second activity and database data is also on 2nd activity itslef.. as soon as I open 2nd activity I need to display list view. How can I achieve this?

Comment: get all data from database & then create Adapter & set it on listview

Comment: Just like @mukesh said, in `onCreate` get data and populate the list.

Comment: Thanks @Mukesh and @Boban S for your adivce.. It worked when I created it in `onCreate` of second activity... Update your answer with this statement.. will accept it as answered.